# Securing Users Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I've got a File Management system in my Rails app that I am building (running locally). Users can create notes and upload documents. Carrierwave allows users to upload an attachment, and the attachment gets the user_id (the view only shows the users documents). Simple Form allows the user to create a note in a different view, and the note gets that user_id, as well.

**Problem:** If I view the url of a note incognito, I get an error No Route matches [GET] "notes/x" (which is fine because we only want the user to see their notes), but if I view the url of a document incognito I can see it (because it is in the `PUBLIC/UPLOADS/DOCUMENTS` folder.

What is the best way to handle securing these uploads? Where should I be storing uploaded files?

**route.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'

  authenticated :user do
    root 'notes#index', as: "authenticated_root"
    resources :notes, :documents, :uploads
  end

  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

**attachment_uploader.rb**

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf doc htm html docx)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two basic choices:

Your best bet is to upload them into a private, non-web-accessable directory on your server. Then, set up a route and controller action to authenticate the user before [sending the file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file). This will ensure that only authenticated users ever have access to their own files. You can prevent the file delivery from tying up a whole thread on your app server by using `X-Sendfile` to do the work with your web server.

A second, less secure, option would be to obfuscate the directory somewhat. It would involve setting a guid on the model, and doing something like:

```
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.guid}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

This will not ensure that unauthorized users are restricted from accessing the file, but it does make it significantly less likely that someone will stumble upon the path. This method should only be considered if it is not absolutely imperative that access to the files is fully restricted.